# Angular2 ng build not working properly

Tags: javascript, angular

So i am using ng build in my angular2 project to create smaller folder size of my project called dist, but once i upload my project to my web host using file transfer protocol(Filezilla) it doesn't show my website. Is there some step i am still missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will always follow steps to deploy my App

1) add script in the package.json

```
"Prod_build": "ng build --base-href /yourappName/ --target=production --aot",
```

2) Run npm run Prod_build

3) copy your dist folder to your webhost.

Answer (score 0):

for prod build, you need to run

```
ng build --prod --aot --base-href /name/
```